# Fortran program producing different errors with the same input parameters

Tags: fortran, osx-mavericks, fortran90

This question may seem slightly open ended, but it's been troubling me for some time so I thought I would post it here in the hope of discussion or advice.

I am a physics PhD student running a fairly large computation on a reasonably complex fortran program. The program involves a large number of particles (~1000) that interact with each other by local potentials and move according to overdamped langevin dynamics.

Recently the program has begun to behave quite strangely. I'm not sure what changed, but it seems that different things are happening when the program is run with the same input parameters. Sometimes the program will run to completion. Other times it will produce a seg fault - at varying points within the computation. Occasionally it seems to simply grind to a halt without producing any errors, and one a couple of occasions has caused my computer to display warnings about running out of program memory.

The thing that confuses me here is why the program should be behaving differently for the same input. I'm really just hoping for suggestions of what might be going on here. Currently my only idea is some kind of memory management problem. The computer I'm running on is a 2013 iMac with 8GB of RAM, a 2.7GHz quad core i5 processor and OSX Mavericks. Not the most powerful in the world but I'm fairly sure I've run bigger computations on it without having these problems.

Comment: I cannot see how anyone can help with that level of information.  Are you able to debug the program at all to find out where it starts to go  whacky?

Comment: You expect a diagnosis without sight of the patient !!??  OK, here are some guesses: failure to insert `implicit none` into each scope; failure to match procedure dummy and actual arguments; accessing arrays outside their bounds, ...  and probably a slew of other issues which can cause what seem to be non-deterministic bugs.  In fact they are always bugs, it's just that they may not always bite you on the bum.

Comment: Not expecting a diagnosis, just hoping for general ideas of what could cause a problem that manifests differently under what seem to be the same conditions, because I've never seen anything like it before.

Comment: In that case: "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs." - voting to close

Comment: Compile with array bounds checking and backtrace and run again. If it does not produce a meaningful error pointing to the issue, run valgrind on it (depending on how big of a simulation it is, this may take a long time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A seg fault indicates that either your program is running out of memory or that your program has an error.  The most common errors in Fortran that cause seg faults are array subscript errors and disagreement between arguments in the call and the procedure (dummy arguments).  For the first, turn on your compiler's option for run-time subscript checking.  For the second, place all procedures into a module (or modules) and use that module (or modules).   This will enable the compiler to check argument consistency.

What compiler are you using?

UPDATE: if you are using gfortran, try these compiler options: `-O2  -fimplicit-none  -Wall -Wline-truncation  -Wcharacter-truncation  -Wsurprising  -Waliasing  -Wimplicit-interface  -Wunused -parameter  -fwhole-file  -fcheck=all  -std=f2008  -pedantic  -fbacktrace`

Comment: I am indeed using gfortran. Simply doing array bound checking has brought to light a couple of problems that I am looking into. I have tried compiling with all of the options you suggest, and although the compiler claims not to recognise "-parameter", the rest have produced a long stream of errors that I will work through steadily. Thanks very much for all the suggestions - this is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.

Comment: I'm glad that helped.  It's `Wunused-parameter`.  It got split across lines, as did `-Wline-truncation`.  These options described in the gfortran manual.  Some of these will produce warning that may be acceptable.  Array bounds violations are not acceptable and might be the cause of the problems with your program.

Comment: Any suggestions for the Intel fortran compiler debugger flags?